# How can I use DataSnapshot to make an ArrayList of all the data that I have in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database, types

My problem is that I have a database in Firebase where I store "Day" Objects, 
and I want to retrieve all the content of the database and put everything in an ArrayList of Days BUT when I execute the code to do it, I have an error : "Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.android_project_test.Day"  and I have no idea on how to resolve it.

I tried casting it, but it didn't work.

The message is :

```
2019-04-20 17:52:18.158 12477-12477/com.example.android_project_test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android_project_test, PID: 12477
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.android_project_test.Day
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source:209)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:10)
        at com.example.android_project_test.CalendarDbHelper.fetchData(CalendarDbHelper.java:125)
        at com.example.android_project_test.CalendarDbHelper.access$000(CalendarDbHelper.java:12)
        at com.example.android_project_test.CalendarDbHelper$1.onChildAdded(CalendarDbHelper.java:58)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzbt.zza(Unknown Source:71)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source:71)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Here is my Day Class :

```
public class Day {

    private String id;
    private String dayName;
    private String dayDate;
    private ArrayList<Meal> meals;

    Day(){}

    Day(String id, String dayName, String dayDate, ArrayList<Meal> meals) {
        this.id = id;
        this.dayName = dayName;
        this.dayDate = dayDate;
        this.meals = meals;

    }

    Day(String dayName, String dayDate, ArrayList<Meal> meals) {
        this.dayName = dayName;
        this.dayDate = dayDate;
        this.meals = meals;

    }

    Day(String dayName, String dayDate) {
        this.dayName = dayName;
        this.dayDate = dayDate;

    }
```

Here is how I add Days into the database :

```
public void addDay(Day day)
    {
                String Id = db.push().getKey();
                day.setId(Id);
                db.child(Id).setValue(day); 
   }
```

Here is the method I use to retrieve an ArrayList from the database :

```
public ArrayList<Day> listDays()
    {


        db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                fetchData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                fetchData(dataSnapshot);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        return listDays;
    }
```

Here is the fetchData(dataSnapshot) where I have a problem :

```
private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        for(DataSnapshot postSnapShot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            Day day= postSnapShot.getValue(Day.class);
            listDays.add(day);

        }
    }
```

When I want to do "Day day = postSnapShot.getValue(Day.class);", what I want to do is to retrieve each child as a Day object. But what I'm getting is the message I've written above.

Comment: Can you please also share `db` object initialization and snapshot of database scheme in the firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your fetchData(dataSnapshot) as given below

```
private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
{
        Day day= dataSnapshot.getValue(Day.class);
        listDays.add(day);
}
```

In your code the fetchData() method iterates through the children of a single object which will return string values

Answer (score 0):

you have set a childEventListener. is not the same as a valueEventListener.
you get the data child by child.

[look here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)